# Need help in using the 'analyze-in-stages' option of the vacuumdb command

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, vacuum

I have a PostgreSQL 10 cluster containing many databases, the total size is 500 Gb. I have launched the vacuumdb command using the *analyze-in-stages* option :

```
vacuumdb --all --verbose --analyze-in-stages
```

and I have seen in the output :

```
vacuumdb: processing database "db1": Generating minimal optimizer statistics (1 target)
vacuumdb: processing database "db2": Generating minimal optimizer statistics (1 target)
...
vacuumdb: processing database "dbN": Generating minimal optimizer statistics (1 targets)
vacuumdb: processing database "db1": Generating medium optimizer statistics (10 targets)
vacuumdb: processing database "db2": Generating medium optimizer statistics (10 targets)
...
vacuumdb: processing database "dbN": Generating medium optimizer statistics (10 targets)
vacuumdb: processing database "db1": Generating default (full) optimizer statistics
....
```

So I understand that the VACUUM is processing in stages: mininal, medium, default using a target but how is controled this "target" ? Which parameter is it ? Is there more stages as it is not yet terminated ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's been a long time since you asked the question. If you remember, why did you use the "--analyze-in-stages" option? It is recommended to be used in case of upgrade or dump.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-vacuumdb.html

Answer (score 2):

I have found an answer looking into the history of code : [vacuumdb: Add option --analyze-in-stages](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=c92c3d50d7fbe7391b5fc864b444346b2db29ffe)

There are indeed 3 stages using this parameters :

1. minimal : "SET default_statistics_target=1; SET vacuum_cost_delay=0;"
2. medium :  "SET default_statistics_target=10; RESET vacuum_cost_delay;"
3. default (full) : "RESET default_statistics_target;"

ref. [diff vacuumdb.c](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blobdiff;f=src/bin/scripts/vacuumdb.c;h=1e288ef978cec3cb6f6fc0f7dd381c15288ef255;hp=07a60d0b6d4db4c5ed90ab17a610158ab8389b22;hb=c92c3d50d7fbe7391b5fc864b444346b2db29ffe;hpb=0d3b2b80aa6aee753f372bb0300a131691e9f55c)